# How can I stop Finder from trying to 'pre-load' audio files?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, finder

I have a lot of audio in my storage devices.

Finder for Mac OS X Snow Leopard tries to get a 'snapshot' of the audio whenever a folder is opened and this can take a while if there are lots of files. It seems to integrate iTunes with the Finder so that audio can be played directly from the Finder icon and not just in iTunes.

I don't want Finder to do this, I just want it to list the files with normal icons and then I can pick which to play. Normal listing happens almost instantly whereas audio pre-loading takes a while.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`View > Show View Options >` uncheck `Show Icon Preview`

(If you're in List view or Icon view, click `Use as Defaults` to make it the default). Repeat for each view mode as necessary.

Hope this helps....